# Quando eu executo aparece o erro: "Car() takes no arguments". Alguém pode me ajudar? Não sei o que fiz errado

Tags: python, funções, classes

```
class Car():
    """Uma tentativa simples de representar um carro."""
    
    def _init_(self, make, model, year):
        """Inicializa os atributos que descrevem um carro."""
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        
    def get_descripte_name(self):
        """Devolve um nome descritivo, formatado de modo elegante."""
        long_name = str(self.year) + " " + self.make + " " + self.model
        return long_name.title()
        
my_new_year = Car("audi", "a4", 2016)
print(my_new_year.get_descripte_name())
```

Comment: resumidamente seu init está só com um underline de cada lado, deveria ser "_ _ init _ _" (sem espaços), como essa classe ia definir o construtor com 3 entradas, por não existir ela assume o padrão, que é zero, ai o erro ocorre por você tentar passar 3

Comment: Obrigada, agora deu certo.

Comment: O nome do construtor deve ser `__init__`, com dois `_` no início e mais dois no final. Tem um erro de digitação tb, na variável `my_new_year`, que deveria ser `my_new_car`: https://ideone.com/sEVz7K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flávia, acredito que baste ajusta a assinatura do seu método init para a descrita abaixo:

```
  def __init__(self, make, model, year):
```

O método init, deve usar sempre dois `_` como prefixo e sufixo em seu nome. Bem fácil de 'passar', também já vivi essa!

Além disto, acredito que você esteja usando o nome incorreto da variável com a instância de carro no exemplo citado. Tente da forma abaixo (e se possível ajuste também o exemplo):

```
my_new_car = Car("audi", "a4", 2016)
print(my_new_car.get_descripte_name())
```